# Copy large amount of file - better to "pull" or to "push"?

Tags: robocopy, copy

I need to copy a large amount from "old" server to "new" server. Both servers are Windows Servers

Is there a difference if I go onto old server, access new server by unc path and "push" files onto new server   vs.  going onto "new" server and then reading ("pull") files from old server?

I use either normal copy action in explorer window or robocopy

Comment: Nope. Just the initiation

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) the newer server could be a bit faster as fileserver if it has a faster CPU (push)

Comment: The answer to this is going to depend on the specific protocol. I don't know the protocol in question but based on my experience with other protocols I'd expect the pull approach to be a bit more reliable.